# How to generate a custom button that submits cell data from its uid in Kendo UI Grid MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am new to Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC and I wanted to create a customized action button on a grid and retrieve some data when that button is clicked based on each unique row.

Here is my grid's code

```
@(Html.Kendo()
      .Grid<PromotionVM>()
      .Name("PromotionsGrid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(c => c.Merchant);
          columns.Bound(c => c.Item);
          columns.Bound(c => c.Image);
          columns.Bound(c => c.DiscountRate);
          columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Approve").Click("ApprovePromotion"))
              .Title("Action");
      })
      .DataSource(source =>
      {
          source.Ajax()
              .Model(model => model.Id(field => field.Id))
              .Read(read => read.Action("GetPromotions", "Promotion"));
      })
      )
```

Here is the `PromotionVM`:

```
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Merchant { get; set; }
    public string Branch { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public decimal DiscountRate { get; set; }
```

and here is the javascript function that I want to call to do an ajax request 
when I am able to get the "Id" column value from the Grid upon button click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ApprovePromotion(e) {

}
</script>
```

Notice that the function is empty because I have no idea what to do here yet.

Please help if you can.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty open ended question, but as an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ApprovePromotion(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // grab data for row
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

    // make ajax call
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            // pass data to controller parameters
            ItemID: dataItem.Id,
            OtherField: dataItem.OtherField
        },
        success: function (response) {
            // On success do something. I'll switch to index
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "MyController")';
        }
    });

}
</script>
```